# Language where pumping does not work -- Pumping lemma

Tags: pumping-lemma

[image: This is a problem I have been trying to understand but i simply cannot.]

I understand that the length of y must be greater than 0 but I do not understand how to show B_2 is a regular language or why pumping up does not work in part ii.

Comment: What's $\Sigma$? Tried anything to attack either question? As for why this language is regular, see whether $000010$ is, or $0011000000000$

Answer (score 0):

For (i), the pumping lemma says there is *some* such division, not that any division you happen to choose has to work. For (ii), because any string starting and ending in $0$ is in the language ($x$ is anything whatsoever in it's definition).